# Expected number of trials ; probability increases after each failure

Tags: probability, random-variables

In Black Desert Online, you can equip some gear (for example a sword) and also enhance its level from +1 to +15, then PRI, DUO, TRI, TET and PEN, but these are really only fancy words to say +16 to +20.

When you enhance your gear, you have a probability $p_{e,f}$ of success, where $e$ is the enhancement level and $f$ is your current number of failed trials (it is called "failstack").
The failstack $f$ increases by $1$ each time you fail an enhancement and is reset to $k$ after each success.
This gives us [big tables of probabilities](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1folCDSzYD8JQMT9tJHxJtmwy9CXVAO3SQegdESQKLk4/htmlview?usp=sharing&sle=true) for any gear that can be enhanced.
If you take a look carefully, you'll realize that most of the probabilities are linearly increasing with the failstack.

When you fail at enhancing, the durability of your gear decrease by some amount. So, when trying to reduce costs, it is best to try to enhance expensive gear using a failstack built using cheap gear.

There's also another thing: you can actually decrease the enhancement level of an item from +15 to +14, and it's guaranteed to success.

Here I am interested in the expected number of trials to enhance an item from +14 to +15.
So far, I have the following:
$$E(T)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n(p+(n-1)s\prod_{i=0}^{n-2}(1-p-is)$$
where $p$ is any initial probability and $s$ the increase after one failed trial.

Any idea how to simplify this expression ?